# Generate alert when values of sensor and temp are more than a threshold over a minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cursor

Consider a table with 3 columns:

1. `Timestamp`: format `hh:mm:ss`, which gets recorded in table each second
2. `PSI`: value of a sensor recorded in table for each second
3. `Temp`: temperature value recorded in table each second

I want to write a query which would generate a alert when

- if `PSI` is greater than 60 and `Temp` is greater than 255 for more than 60 seconds or more continuously

For e.g. if the value of `PSI > 60 and Temp > 255` from 01:01:15 to 01:02:17, an alert should be generated.

I tried using cursor to get this work, but the query is not working correctly. Can someone help with the existing query? Also, can someone please suggest alternate and simple query to this problem statement?

Query I tried:

```
declare @Timestamp time, @PSI int, @Temp int, @final_timestmp time, @status int 
set @final_timestmp='01:00:00'

declare cr_alert cursor for
    select Timestamp, PSI, Temp
    from [dbo].[Sensor_Values]
    where PSI > 60 and Temp > 255
    order by Timestamp

open cr_alert;

Fetch next from cr_alert into @Timestamp, @PSI, @Temp

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @status = 0
    print @status

    if (@Timestamp <> @final_timestmp)
    begin
        set @status = datediff(second, @final_timestmp, @Timestamp)

        if (@status = 1)
        begin
            set @final_timestmp = @Timestamp;

            insert into final_Sensor_Values 
                select @final_timestmp, @PSI, @Temp

            fetch next from cr_alert into @Timestamp, @PSI, @Temp
        end
    end
end

close cr_alert;
deallocate cr_alert;
```

Sample dataset:

```
Timestamp   PSI Temp
01:01:01    59  264
01:01:02    63  247
01:01:03    56  245
01:01:04    64  262
01:01:05    50  245
01:01:06    57  244
01:01:07    64  251
01:01:08    60  259
01:01:09    52  244
01:01:10    52  242
01:01:11    63  259
01:01:12    56  241
01:01:13    51  252
01:01:14    52  261
01:01:15    50  265
01:01:16    54  251
01:01:17    59  243
01:01:18    64  240
01:01:19    55  265
```

OR you can view the dataset in below url.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGJlq.png

Comment: What is not working with the query? Any errors? Sample data would really help to understand.

Comment: Added sample dataset in first edit. There is no particular error, it just goes in infinite loop. Also, looking for a simple query where I do not have to use the cursor.

Comment: What is the expected output for this data?

Comment: Output: Should generate an alert or print message when count of condition (PSI>60 and Temp>255) is more than 60 seconds consecutively without break in between. I hope I'm clear now.

Comment: What do you expect when you bury the loop increment in an IF statement? And ALWAYS specify the column list when inserting. Lastly your over-simplified sample set will cause NOTHING to be flag because it spans 19 seconds. Worse, your code starts with a literal that is more than 1 sec different from any sample value. So when do you expect that related IF statement to do anything?

Comment: And one word of caution. Rarely is data ever so neatly and precisely recorded in real life. If you expect and rely on precise 1 second boundaries in your data for your logic to work, then you should verify that first, document that in your code, and then do something (like throw an error) if that assumption is ever violated.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
Timestamp time,
PSI smallint,
Temp smallint,
index clidx clustered(Timestamp)
--id int identity,
--primary key clustered(Timestamp, id)
);


insert into @t(Timestamp, PSI, Temp)
values
('01:01:01', 59, 264),
('01:01:02', 63, 247),
('01:01:03', 56, 245),
('01:01:04', 64, 262),
('01:01:05', 50, 245),
('01:01:06', 57, 244),
('01:01:07', 64, 251),
('01:01:08', 60, 259),
('01:01:09', 52, 244),
('01:01:10', 52, 242),
('01:01:11', 63, 259),
('01:01:12', 56, 241),
('01:01:13', 51, 252),
('01:01:14', 52, 261),
('01:01:15', 50, 265),
('01:01:16', 54, 251),
('01:01:17', 59, 243),
('01:01:18', 64, 240),
('01:01:19', 55, 265);

select *, case when l.totalrows = 5 and l.minPSI > 50 and l.minTemp > 240 then 1 else 0 end as AlertYN
from @t as t
cross apply
(
    select min(p.PSI) as minPSI, max(p.PSI) as maxPSI, min(p.Temp) as minTemp, max(p.Temp) as maxTemp, count(*) as totalrows
    from @t as p 
    where p.TimeStamp > dateadd(second, -5, t.TimeStamp) --check for last 5 secs
      and p.TimeStamp <= t.TimeStamp
) as l
--where l.minPSI > 50 and l.minTemp > 240
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row for each second, you can use window functions:

```
select sv.*,
       (case when min(temp) over (order by timestamp rows between 59 preceding and current row) > 255 and
                  min(PSI) over (order by timestamp rows between 59 preceding and current row) > 60
             then 'Alert!!!'
        end) as alert                  
from [dbo].[Sensor_Values] sv;
```

If seconds could be missing, you can use:

```
with sv as (
      select sv.*, row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from [dbo].[Sensor_Values] sv
     )
select sv.*,
       (case when min(temp) over (order by seqnum range between 59 preceding and current row) > 255 and
                  min(PSI) over (order by seqnum range between 59 preceding and current row) > 60
             then 'Alert!!!'
        end) as alert                  
from [dbo].[Sensor_Values] sv;
```

The only caution here is that this might generated unnecessary alerts at the beginning of the data.